# Python - Rolled 2 6-side die 1000 times

Tags: python-2.7

This is for a programming class using python2. Instructions are to simulate rolling a pair of die 1000 times, store the results in a list and display the percentage of time each roll occurs.

Example of what output should be:

- Rolled 2 27 times, or 2.7%
- Rolled 3 54 times, or 5.4%
- Rolled 4 75 times, or 7.5%
- Rolled 5 101 times, or 10.1%
- Rolled 6 157 times, or 15.7%

Here's my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

rolls = [0]*12

for v in range(1000):
d1 = random.randint(1,6)
d2 = random.randint(1,6)
rolls[d1 + d2 -1] += 1

print("Rolled %s %d times, or %.2f %" % (str(rolls)))
```

Right now I'm getting "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string".

I realize that I need to define a reference for %d and %.2f (and I realize that using %'s is going the way of .format, but this is how the professor has asked for it - hasn't taught how to use .format).  I'm not sure how to reference the %d and the %.2f.

I know the %d needs to be a count of how many times a certain number was rolled, but am stuck at how to define and reference it.  The %.2f needs to use the definition for the count/1000.

So, I think in my print line I need something like

```
print("Rolled %s %d times, or %.2f %" % (str(rolls), count, count/1000))
```

Any insight/corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the line indents under your for loop a typo? They should be 1 tab space in.

Comment: I have the indents. They just didn't show in the OP for some reason - sure it was user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary would be another option, and it would look like this:

```
import random

results = {}

for _ in range(1000):
    d1 = random.randint(1,6)
    d2 = random.randint(1,6)
    results[d1+d2] = results.setdefault(d1+d2, 1) + 1

for roll, count in results.iteritems():
    print('Rolled %d %d times, or %.2f %%' % (roll, count, count/1000.))
```

`setdefault` will set a key to a value if it doesn't exist, otherwise it will return the value of the key.

Comment: This did it!  Big thanks to you and Ben for helping with links and explaining the %% and setdefault syntax. AND for responding so quickly.

Comment: I altered your suggested last line to

   >>>   print('Rolled %s %d times, or %.2f %%" % (roll, count, ((count/1000.)*100.)))    <<<

to move the decimal place to show the true percentage. (I'm totally failing at marking up the posts, so forgive the extra chars & lack of formatting).

Comment: @user3426455 remember to accept the answer if it was useful

Comment: thnx for the reminder! Script blocker had those options blocked, but think I got it marked =)

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the Python Docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

But for each `%` you need a value to substitute in:

```
for roll_value, roll_count in enumerate(rolls):
    print "Rolled %s %d times, or %.2f %%" %((roll_value+1), roll_count, (roll_count/1000.)*100)
```

*note the `%%` to print out the `%`sign, and the `1000.` to return a type `float`

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is not 100% correct because he/she added is returning or setting default to 1 and then adding another one which is incrementing total count.  Total count will be over 1000 in that case.    Here is the correct code:

```
for _ in range(1000):
    d1 = random.randint(1,6)
    d2 = random.randint(1,6)
    results[d1+d2] = results.setdefault(d1+d2, 0) + 1

for roll, count in results.iteritems():
    print('Rolled %d %d times, or %.2f %%' % (roll, count, count/1000))
```